# Knp/Snappy PDF Generator Blank Page

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

I'im doing a generator with symfony/twig, but always there are empty pages.(sometimes 1 , sometimes more)
here is my JS about pages:
    var marginTop = 15;

```
         var cellHeightArray = [];
         var rowCounter = 0;
         var cellCounter = 0;
         var cellHeightArray2 = [];
         var rowCounter2 = 0;
         var cellCounter2 = 0;

         $('.page-three > .spec-box').each(function() {
            if(!cellHeightArray[rowCounter]) {
                cellHeightArray[rowCounter] = [];
            }
            var height = $(this).height();
            var topHeight = 0;

            for(var j = 0; j < cellHeightArray.length; j++) {
                if(cellHeightArray[j][cellCounter]) {
                    topHeight += cellHeightArray[j][cellCounter] + marginTop;
                }
            }

            cellHeightArray[rowCounter][cellCounter] = height;

            $(this).css({
               "float": "left",
               "position": "absolute",
               "width": "400px",
               "top": topHeight,
               "left": (cellCounter * (400 + 50)) + 50
            });

            if (topHeight + height > 750) {
                $(this).appendTo(".page-four");
                $("page-four").append("Some appended text.");
            }

            if(cellCounter == 2) {
                rowCounter++;
                cellCounter = 0;
            }else {
                cellCounter++;
            }

         });
```

**NOTE:**: its landscape page. And in my controller all margins => 0 and javascript enabled. What should i do? I googled it , someone talking about its a bug, but idk really. I think im doing something wrong.

And here is my CSS for page-one and two

```
.page-one, .page-two {
                font-family: Roboto, 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;
                position: relative;
                height:992px;
            }
```

And the page-three CSS

```
.page-three, .page-four{
                font-family: Roboto, 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;
                position:relative;
                height:992px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved same issue just like this:

CSS Code:

```
.page {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

After, put this class "page" on every div o section that you need show. Remove all height from div o section-